# replacing nan dates using a date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a dataframe that has two columnns: date and number of passesngers. The date column has dates ranges from 1950 to 2019. However some dates are recorded as 1600 which is definetly an error. When i try to change the date object to datetimeindex i get an out of bounds error which makes sense. So i decided to first replace the 1600 dates with nan values instead

```
new_set=drop_dup.replace(to_replace =["1610-01-01", "1610/01/01"], 
             value = np.nan)
```

This was just a temporary fix to change the date obect into datetimeindex. The dates with 1600 as a value are about 27 and i didnt want to change them to a single value. Instead i want to replace those nan values with a certain date range i.e from 1955 - 1982. The below code does not work but i was aiming for something like that

```
new_set=drop_dup.replace(to_replace =np.nan, value = pd.date_range(start='1-1-1955', end='1-1-1982', freq='12M')
```

So the 27 1600 dates should range from the period 1955 to 1982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime([np.nan] * 10 + 
                                          ['2000-01-31','2001-01-31','2002-01-31'])})
print (df)
         date
0         NaT
1         NaT
2         NaT
3         NaT
4         NaT
5         NaT
6         NaT
7         NaT
8         NaT
9         NaT
10 2000-01-31
11 2001-01-31
12 2002-01-31
```

First idea is create mask for missing data and append `date_range` without end parameter, but with `period` by number of missing values created by `sum`:

```
m = df['date'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'date'] = pd.date_range(start='1-1-1955', freq='12M', periods=m.sum())
print (df)
         date
0  1955-01-31
1  1956-01-31
2  1957-01-31
3  1958-01-31
4  1959-01-31
5  1960-01-31
6  1961-01-31
7  1962-01-31
8  1963-01-31
9  1964-01-31
10 2000-01-31
11 2001-01-31
12 2002-01-31
```

Another idea is remove `start` and to parameter `end` is added minimal date and to period also count of missing values:

```
m = df['date'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'date'] = pd.date_range(end=df['date'].min(), freq='12M', periods=m.sum())
print (df)
         date
0  1991-01-31
1  1992-01-31
2  1993-01-31
3  1994-01-31
4  1995-01-31
5  1996-01-31
6  1997-01-31
7  1998-01-31
8  1999-01-31
9  2000-01-31
10 2000-01-31
11 2001-01-31
12 2002-01-31
```

Comment: i tried the above but i keep getting a type error ''series'' object not callable

Comment: @Tamarie - How is changed your solution working for Series ?

Comment: it just worked, turned out i missed the sum() at the end